# d3 basic append example not working

Tags: d3.js, append

I'm just starting with d3 instead of the usual jquery but even their basic example doesn't seem to actually append anything. Nothing is being added to any of my section tags:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="stats">
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
var section = d3.selectAll("section");

section.append("div")
    .html("First!");

section.append("div")
    .html("Second.");
  </script>
<section>asfd</section>
<section>erasdf</section>
<section>asdfq</section>
<section>asdfasdfas</section>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try moving your d3 code to the bottom, it seems you are trying to select a section before it actually exists in the DOM

Comment: quick fiddle put together...[works](http://jsfiddle.net/G8jja/)...

Comment: Thanks Josh but the d3 is defined. I've looked in the console and i get the method hints when typing d3.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Hm. I have the latest d3 source. I've tried setting up a localhost just in case but that didn't work either. I don't get any console errors so it is finding the d3 script and loading it.

Comment: @user3618110 d3 is defined yes, the problem (I think) is that there are no `section` elements yet, so when you try to select them, it returns nothing, and therefore doesn't append the divs, etc.

Comment: @Josh is right...here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZOOjBeAGuxFC47iqxfM?p=preview) to settle this.

Comment: Well I'd mark this as answered but I'm not seeing a checkmark to do so. It's answered.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why **your append is not working is because you have added the script first and your `<section>` later**.Since the script tag is first , the script will get executed first,when `selectAll("section")` is executed it searches for section tag to append, but it does not exist, since the section tag is after the script. In order for it to work correctly , **move your script to the bottom**.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="stats">
</head>

<body>

<section>asfd</section>
<section>erasdf</section>
<section>asdfq</section>
<section>asdfasdfas</section>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hi</p>

 <script type="text/javascript"src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
var section = d3.selectAll("section");

section.append("div")
    .html("First!");

section.append("div")
    .html("Second.");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```